# Scala how to create file to array

Tags: scala

I have a file as below,

```
AB*xyz*1234~
CD*mny*769~
MN*bvd*2345~
AB*zar*987~
```

here i would like to split the data using(*) and line always ends with ~.

code.

```
val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(sample.txt)
    var array = Array[String]()
    for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines()) {
      array = line.split("\\~")
      val splittedRow=array.split("\\*")

      }
```

I want output as below which should be first words from all lined,

Array(AB,CD,MN,AB).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().map(line => line.split("\\*").head).toArray
//res0: Array[String] = Array(AB, CD, MN, AB)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better achieved by mapping over the lines from the file, and selecting the part of the string you want to keep:

```
val array = 
  Source.fromFile(sample.txt)  // Open the file
    .getLines()                // get each line
    .toArray                   // as an array
    .map(s => s.split("\\*").head)  // Then select just the first part
                                    // of the line, split by * characters
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i am getting the output as [Ljava.lang.String;@a92be4f .

Comment: i converted the array to list and got the expected output.

Comment: That's because `Array`s don't print out their contents like `List`s do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `collect` to get what you want

```
val s = Source.fromFile("fileName").getLines().collect{
  case e => e.split("\\*").apply(0)
}.toArray
//s: Array[String] = Array(AB, CD, MN, AB)
```